# Magento 1.9 RWD responsive breakpoint/media query iPad (4 and 1,2) landscape and separately iPad portrait

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I need to add specific styles for [my Responsive site](http://magento.futurumshop.nl/en) for iPad landscape, but also iPad portrait. What are breakpoints (like `@include bp(max-width, $bp-medium) {}` ?), which effect separately:

- only iPad 4 landscape
- only iPad 1 or 2 landscape
- only iPad 4 portrait
- only iPad 1 or 2 portrait

Or maybe some new mixins which i can add?

I really need this because i have to style the menu and icons on iPad Landscape and Portrait.

Comment: It's a bad idea to design a website based on certain devices as this will mean that anyone else not using an iPad will potentially have issues viewing the website.

Answer (score 2):

See the various viewport sizes for ipads: http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=ipad

You can then define variables with these sizes in your skin scss/_var.scss file. You should see the various breakpoint variables defined from line 49 onwards (if you haven't changed those lines till now). After you define the breakpoints as variables you can then use them, for eg:

`@include bp(max-width, $ipad-1-potrait) {}`

Comment: Thanks! I discovered iPad 4 is only reacting on `min-device-width` instead of `min-width` (or am i wrong?). How do i add this? And how do i handle `min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` and `min-device-pixel-ratio: 1` in your example?

Comment: your answer its working now on iPad (portrait and landscape). But when i resize my **normal** browser the iPad styles also effecting. How can i **exclude** those styles for the normal browser?

Comment: Media queries is for width, not the device type. The term *normal* browser is quite vast even if you classify for touch vs non-touch screens. For eg., what about laptops which have touch screen? In responsive design field, it's best to just make a single website and make it responsive based on width rather than device. But after understanding this if you must separate then create separate sub-theme and look at http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-design-exceptions-explained/